# Editing a contact that has no Account and are owned by others

Tags: administration, profile, user, permission-sets, owd

With Contacts that has Public read/write in sharing settings and the user has read,edit,create,view all permissions only. The user will not be 
able to edit the contacts owned by other users unless the profiles has "Modify All"  or the contact is related to an account. If the contact is not related to the
an account then User will not be able to edit it as contact will be considered as private.

I think there are only two solutions for this:

1. Provide modify all permissions to the profile that i trying to edit the contact
2. Setup Role Hierarchy - I don't want to setup the roles now.

Other than above two options is there anything else that can make users able to edit the records. THere are 50+ users(5 profiles)  wants to edit the contact without
an account associated with it.

Comment: I don't understand. If Sharing Settings for Contact are 'Public read/write" then anybody will be able to see/write all contacts....

Comment: User cannot edit others record if there is no account associated with that contact. It would say insufficient privilege.

Comment: It shouldn't, with those sharing settings.

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrOs . Contact without an Account becomes Private even though sharing setting is Public read/write.

Comment: Learned something new today.

Comment: LOL - even I did.